# Chrome browser is diagonally splited on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome

I just updated to Google Chrome Stable version 87.0.4280.88-1 on Ubuntu 18.04 running LXDE. And my Chrome window looks like this

[image]

It is not usable. How do I fix the issue?

Comment: Did you try turning off hardware acceleration? `Settings / Advanced / System / Hardware acceleration` (if you can reach that on your screen)

Comment: Thanks. I tried "google-chrome --disable-gpu" but got the same problem. I cannot get to settings.

Comment: This is strange. Resizing the browser window makes the problem disappear and reappear.

Comment: Turning off `Hardware acceleration` did not make a difference (same diagonal line, problem disappears/reappears when resizing).

Comment: Applies to some of the pop-up dialog boxes as well: three dots -> (dialog file) -> expand Help -> (dialog split diagonally)

Comment: Google Chrome stable: 88.0.4324.96-1

Comment: Managed to send feedback with screenshot. I think screenshot includes the busted behavior, but it was hard to tell because the "Send feedback to Google" dialog is also busted the same way.

Note that this is just a UI issue. The checkboxes and text are still in the original place in the dialog.

Ubuntu: 14.04.6 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Short-term: resize the window, some sizes show up normally.

Long-term: Upgrade to 90.0.4430.72 to make the problem go away.